# How Do I get windows system's logged in username in Angular app

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2.0. I made a simple app where I need to fetch system's (windows/iso) loggedin username.

Is it possible? if yes how?
thanks in advance

Comment: Angular 2.0 is known as Angular and Angular 1.x is known as AngularJS , for your info.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can not get get Windows Logged in Username because AngularJS/Angular is a client side application and only has access to the variables that are delcared in the browser's window object.

Comment: thanks wasif.. but is there any alternate way to get system username?

Comment: In simple words, you are asking about getting information of user, in other words hacking

Comment: no not exactly hacking.. I just want to send that system username to sharepoint app

Comment: I dont think it is possible, get username of system by any input field or something like that.